# A closed Riemannian manifold of nonpositive sectional curvature with finite $\pi_1 (M)$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, curvature

Let $ \left( M,g \right)$ be a closed Riemannian manifold of nonpositive sectional curvature $K \leq 0$. Is there then a variety with a finite fundamental group $\pi_1 \left(M \right)$. I know that if our manifold is compact and $K < 0$ then by the Preissman's theorem its fundamental group doesn't need to contain any abelian subgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Cartan-Hadamard theorem a manifold with a complete metric of non-positive sectional curvature has universal cover diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. If $M$ is compact this implies that that $\pi_{1}(M)$ is infinite, since it acts on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with a compact quotient space.

Comment: But if it is not compact?

Comment: Then $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with the flat metric is simply connected. In your question $M$ is assumed to be a closed manifold, which is compact by definition.